# First and last value aggregate functions in postgresql that work correctly with NULL values

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I know there are aggregate functions for getting last and first value of rows in [postgresql](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_%28aggregate%29)

My problem is, that they do not work as i need. And i could use the help of one postgresql wizard. I'm using postgresql 9.2 - in case the version makes offering solution easyer.

Query

```
select v.id, v.active, v.reg_no, p.install_date, p.remove_date 
from vehicle v 
    left join period p on (v.id = p.car_id) 
where v.id = 1 
order by v.id, p.install_date asc
```

Returns 6 rows:

```
id, active, reg_no, install_date, remove_date
1, TRUE, something, 2008-08-02 11:13:39, 2009-02-09 10:32:32
....
1, TRUE, something, 2010-08-15 21:16:40, 2012-08-25 07:44:30
1, TRUE, something, 2012-09-10 17:05:12, NULL
```

But when i use aggregating query:

```
select max(id) as id, last(active) as active, first(install_date) as install_date, last(remove_date) as remove_date 
from (
    select v.id, v.active, v.reg_no, p.install_date, p.remove_date 
    from vehicle v 
      left join period p on (v.id = p.car_id) 
    where v.id = 1 
    order by v.id, p.install_date asc
) as bar 
group by id
```

Then i get

```
id, active, install_date, remove_date
1, TRUE, 2008-08-02 11:13:39, 2012-08-25 07:44:30
```

not

```
id, active, install_date, remove_date
1, TRUE, 2008-08-02 11:13:39, NULL
```

as i expected

Is it possible to change the aggregate functions somehow to yield NULL if the value of last row is null, not last existing value?

**EDIT1**

[Roman Pekar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1744834/roman-pekar) offered [alternative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345859/first-and-last-value-aggregate-functions-in-postgresql-that-work-correctly-with/20346066#20346066) to my problem, but that does not fit my needs. The reason is - i simplified the original query. But the query i run is more complex. I realise that there might be alternative solutions to my problem - this why is update the post to include the original, more complex, query. Which is:

```
select partner_id, sum(active) as active, sum(installed) as installed, sum(removed) as removed 
from (
    select 
    pc.partner_id as partner_id, 
    v.id, 
    CASE WHEN v.active = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as active, 
    CASE WHEN first(p.install_date) BETWEEN '2013-12-01' AND '2014-01-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as installed,
    CASE WHEN last(p.remove_date) BETWEEN '2013-12-01' AND '2014-01-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as removed 
    from vehicle v 
        left join period p on (v.id = p.car_id) 
        left join partner_clients pc on (pc.account_id = v.client_id) 
    group by pc.partner_id, v.id, v.active
) as foo group by partner_id
```

As you can see, i actually need to get first and last value of several vehicles not one and in the end aggregate the counts of those vehicles by the owners of those vehicles.

**/EDIT1**

Comment: You've linked to a page that shows how you can implement the function yourself, if you wanted to, and points out *how* `NULL`s are being ignored (by referring to `STRICT`). What more do you want?

Comment: Yes thats how far my postgresql knowledge goes - i know how to copy-paste functions from wiki to phpgadmin :P. That is exactly what i did. If you look the query, that i posted, you'll see me using those functions there. What i do not know, though, is what they actually do/mean and how to make them work like i need to. This is why i use stackoverflow :P. What i want is that someone told me how to change those functions so they would do what i need. So what do i need to do with this STRICT to fix my situation?

Comment: I guess i should thank you Damien :P. I switched STRICT for CALLED ON NULL INPUT in those aggregate functions and got them working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Damien i went reading postgresql documentation about creating functions ([source](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createfunction.html)) and fiddled with the function changing it from:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.last_agg ( anyelement, anyelement )
RETURNS anyelement LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT AS $$
        SELECT $2;
$$;

CREATE AGGREGATE public.last (
        sfunc    = public.last_agg,
        basetype = anyelement,
        stype    = anyelement
);
```

to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.last_agg ( anyelement, anyelement )
RETURNS anyelement LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE CALLED ON NULL INPUT AS $$
        SELECT $2;
$$;

CREATE AGGREGATE public.last (
        sfunc    = public.last_agg,
        basetype = anyelement,
        stype    = anyelement
);
```

and it seems to have fixed my troubles.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Alas, this fix only works for "last", not for "first". Because when performing the aggregation, postgresql calls the function first_agg for the first time with arguments (NULL, value_of_the_first_record), so first_agg always returns NULL, also for all subsequent records.  
Possible workaround: use "last" anyway, with descending order: `select last(my_column order by order_column desc)`, which is logically equivalent to `select first(my_column order by order_column)`

Answer (score 6):

You could use window functions [`lead()` and `lag()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-window.html) to check first and last record, for example:

```
select
    max(a.id) as id,
    max(a.first) as first,
    max(a.last) as last
from (
    select
         v.id,
         case when lag(v.id) over(order by v.id, p.install_date) is null then p.install_date end as first,
         case when lead(v.id) over(order by v.id, p.install_date) is null then p.remove_date end as last
    from vehicle v 
       left join period p on (v.id = p.car_id) 
    where v.id = 1 
) as a
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/4ddf5/4)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks. This works in the case i presented - in case of one car. But my problem is, that i'm actually joining one other table there, so the  results of inner query actually contain several vehicles. I'll update the original post. Perhaps you can come up with better answer - or perhaps you can offer insight as how to modify those first and last aggregate functions.

Comment: Modified the original post. If i use your query as subquery, then all the values for other vehicles install and remove dates are NULL.